# How does Ubuntu LVM encryption work?

Tags: ubuntu, encryption, lvm

While installing Ubuntu Server, during the partition step one of the options is "use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" ([see screenshots](http://lsi.vc.ehu.es/pablogn/docencia/configuraciones/ubuntu/en/cryptolvm.html)). Can anyone explain - or at least point to the necessary web pages - how it works under the hood? What kind of tools/technologies/algorithms are used? How exactly does this possibly prevent thieves from getting access to the data in the hard disk?

And finally, how does this compare with Ubuntu's home directory encryption?

[image: Ubuntu installer screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LUKS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup)